Why Am I Not Getting Any Answers or Comments to My Question?
It has been $2$ weeks since I asked this question, but I haven't got any comments or answers. The number of views has stagnated at $110-115$ for the past few days. I don't think I have asked a bad question since it has gathered $6$ upvotes till now. Is there any problem with the tags I used? Is it too trivial to be answered? Or something else that I am not aware about MSE?
Any feedback would be highly appreciated.
Edit: I am new to Math Meta, so kindly comment any suggestions or feedback if my question is of poor quality. It will be help me improve my future questions.

In case some of them might be useful for you, you could have a look at the suggestions here: How to grab users' attention on an old question?
And you could also check out some of other questions linked there.

People are not required to comment when downvoting, but I'll note that asking "what's wrong with my question" usually isn't considered sufficient grounds for opening a meta post. I think asking about this in one of the chat rooms is the standard.

Since @JonathanZ mentioned possibility of getting some feedback in chat, I'll add link to this: List of chatrooms. (One of the answers contains also a list of subject-specific chatrooms.) There is also a room called Helpful Commentary that was created with the intention of getting constructive feedback. Admittedly, very few people visit that room.

Bounties are exactly for this purpose. When putting 50 or 100 points (or more) for grabs, the problem gets a nice blue indicator for bounty and goes to a special bountied section of the front page.

I tend not to engage with questions about integrals, so take my opinion for what it's worth, but I think your question has too many details. About half way through glancing at it I was wondering "what exactly is the issue, and would I have to grind through all these details to figure it out".
Can you reduce it to "In doing this integral foob two people have gotten two different answers, gloop1 and gloop2. I've been told that this doesn't matter, but only for indefinite integrals, and I don't understand why."
Just a suggestion.

What do foob and gloop mean?

Those are just nonsense words that you would replace with whatever your specific details are, like the way the words 'foo' and 'bar' are used in computer programming, if you're familiar with them.

Ah, they are called 'metasyntactic variables ': https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable

@MathGuy Although I have mixed feelings about JonathanZ's answer, I think that he has a very good point.  Personally, I like that you provided so much detail.  However, I didn't attempt to tackle the problem because [1] My calculus knowledge is somewhat iffy, and [2] I am too lazy to wade through all of your details, despite the fact that I think that those details are good.  It is difficult to walk the tightrope between providing the pertinent info very explicitly and not requiring a potential MathSE responder to do so much work to flesh out the issue.
